# jQuery elevateZoom work only when I put an alert() before

Tags: javascript, jquery, elevatezoom

I have this code to launch **jQuery elevateZoom** but, only works if I put an `alert()` before.

I have already try with/without `load()` function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert("Hi");
    $("#sh-product-main-image").load(function(){
        $(this).elevateZoom({
            zoomType: "inner",
            debug : true,
            cursor: "crosshair", 
            zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
            zoomWindowFadeOut: 500
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

This is another variation of the code I have tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert("Hi");
    $("#sh-product-main-image").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        debug : true,
        cursor: "crosshair", 
        zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
        zoomWindowFadeOut: 500
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `$(document).ready()` happens when the DOM is loaded, not when all the images are loaded. The alert causes a delay and allows time for the image to be loaded.

The following should work:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $("#sh-product-main-image").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        debug : true,
        cursor: "crosshair", 
        zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
        zoomWindowFadeOut: 500
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think elevateZoom plugin requires only DOM to be fully loaded in order to work properly, not the Page load! (DOM load is normally recommended over Page load!)

I think the code below would be enough:

```
$(function() { /* Executed after DOM did load */

  $("img#sh-product-main-image").elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "inner",
    debug : true,
    cursor: "crosshair", 
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 500
  });

});
```